# Install longer refrigerator power cord?

Tags: electrical

I live in an apartment in France, and to create space for a dishwasher, I would like to reposition my Bosch refrigerator/freezer (KGN36X03/10). I think it is 10+ years old, and past its warranty.

The problem I am trying to overcome is that the power cord of the refrigerator/freezer is about 1 meter too short for it to reach the existing outlet from the fridge’s imagined new position.

I have read about the drawbacks of using an extension cord in this situation, and I am reluctant to ask the landlord to install a new outlet.

I have seen online explanations for how one might install a fridge’s replacement power cord when the original fails. This approach makes me wonder about the feasibility of installing a replacement power cord that is longer than the OEM cord by about 1 meter. This would probably have to be a custom build, as I can’t seem to find similar cords when I search for them on the internet. So, I would seek to source the appropriate cable and plug and attach them to the fridge.

In my less-than-expert view, this seems safer than using an extension cord. But I was wondering if others might evaluate my idea, and comment on its feasibility and perceived safety? Any advice would be most welcome.

Comment: It should work as long as the cord is same gauge or slightly larger.  The only problem might be how it is attached/connected to the fridge.  It might be a simple connection or they made it difficult.  Check the fridge connection before doing something.

Comment: Is it typical in France for the tenant to own the fridge?

Comment: @jay613 Usually. Unless you rent a furnished apartment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unplug your fridge and determine that the cord is replaceable without too much difficulty.  That means, there is a panel or door that you can remove with screws and without breaking plastic tabs or prying open glued parts, and the cord is attached to the fridge by screw terminals or spade terminals and not solder.   You should in theory be able to remove and replace the same cord in less than half an hour without breaking anything or needing new parts.  Pay attention to the strain relief.

If that can be done, just go to any electrical supplier and tell them what you need.  YOu can surely buy a ready-made power cord of the right wire size in 2m, 3m, etc.  Worst case (but really unlikely) you buy the cable and plug separately but make sure it's a right-angle plug like the one you already have.

On the other hand, if the cord cannot easily be replaced there is nothing wrong with using a *suitable* extension cord installed in a safe manner.  Extension cords are bad because they can be too small (wire), too long, tripping hazards, poor quality, etc.   If you do it well there is nothing wrong with it.  Buy the shortest one that will suit you, make sure the plug and socket are sturdy, the wire is large enough for the load, and make sure it won't get stretched, nicked, cut, or stepped on once installed.

Answer (score 3):

A quick search based on the refrigerator model # found a [replacement cord part 00090885](https://www.bosch-home.com.sg/shop-productlist/00090885):

[image: Bosch power cord]

The connectors on the end look fairly standard to me. I would take the picture to an electrical supply house - they are in every large (and many small) city in the US, and I would expect something similar around the world. You should be able to get *cordage*, which is the technical term for cord with insulated wires in a flexible outer sheath, in the desired length (normally cut to order) and the appropriate connectors for each end. The end that plugs into the wall will often have screw connectors and be very easy to attach. The connectors on the other end are sometimes a bit trickier and may require a special crimping tool to attach. The colors of the wires should be standard for your country/region (in the US they would be black, white and green or bare).